VPN Server/Open VPN certificate updated without warning
I have a Synology Diskstation DS220+. Several months ago I installed the VPN Server package and enabled OpenVPN so I could access files from a remote computer. It all worked fine for about 4 months. Then a few days ago I started getting TLS errors when trying to connect to the VPN using an OpenVPN client and it would not connect. On a hunch I re-exported the configuration using the Synology VPN Server's Export Configuration function. I started comparing the contents of the VPNConfig.ovpn file to what I was using on the client, and when I got to the auth-user-pass section I noticed a difference in the certificate code (<ca> ---BEGIN CERTIFICATE--- ... ---END CERTIFICATE--- </ca>). I copied the new certificate data to my client's configuration file, overwriting the existing data, and then I was able to connect to the VPN again.
My question is, what prompted the VPN Server to update its certificate, and how will I know if/when this happens again so I don't get stuck without access to the VPN?

Okay, I found that the VPN Server is using the certificate found at Control Panel->Security->Certificate, and I see that that certificate was just updated on 9/30, which is when I started having issues. However, my question about how I will know if/when this certificate gets updated again remains.

When does the certificate expire? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

When I saw 9/30 I assumed that was indicating the date that the certificate was last updated. But now I see that the year is 2025 not 2024, so it is obviously an expiration date.

The certificate and its expiration date are found in Control Panel->Security->Certificate. Apparently the certificate auto-renews on the expiration date. (It was apparently updated on 9/30/2024, as that is about when I started having issues and would be one year prior to the current expiration date.)


Its standard for self-signed certificates to be good for specific timeframes. You can use a browser to see the starting date, if I were to guess, the certificate is valid for a year

Yes, and I'm not surprised by that. The real issue here was that all of this happened automatically out of sight, so when a (automatic) change affected something I was using, I had no idea what the cause was or where to look for answers.
